# PHP Regex to extract metric sizes

Tags: php, regex, extract

I'm trying to extract some metric sizes from strings example:

Example:

```
$s1=" foobar 10mm bar"              // 10mm
$s2=" foobar 10-300ml barbr"        // 10-300ml
$s3=" foobar 25 - 70 cm foo"        // 25-70cmm
```

How do I go about it ?

I've tried this so:

```
$sizes_volume_distance_markers = array('mm','ml','l','cm');
static  $pattern_final_voldist;
    if(!$pattern_final_voldist)
    {
        $pattern_final_voldist =   implode("|",self::$sizes_volume_distance_markers);
    }

if(preg_match_all("/([\d.-]{1,4}[\s.-]{0,2}($pattern_final_voldist) {1,2})+/i",$str,$vvalues))
       {
              var_dump($vvalues);
       }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post your current attempt so that we can see where your problem is? Please note that this site is about helping with specific problems, not a place to have someone else do your homework.

Comment: Regex could be: ([\d -]+(mm|ml|cm))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should works, add other suffixes in last parentheses:

```
/(\d+\s+?\-\s+?)?(\d+)\s+?(mm|ml|cm)/gi
```

Usage:

```
$source=" foobar 10mm bar   foobar 10-300ml barbr  foobar 25 - 70 cm foo" 
preg_match_all("/(\d+\s+?\-\s+?)?(\d+)\s+?(mm|ml|cm)/i",$source, $results);
```

If you need to match floats use this instead:

```
/(\d+(\.\d+)?\s+?\-\s+?)?(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s+?(mm|ml|cm)/gi
```

Comment: To accommodate a period ?
    $s="foobar 2.7 - 1.7mm "